# Find a subsequence of length k whose sum is equal to given sum

Tags: algorithm, sum, subsequence

Given an array `A` and a `sum`, I want to find out if there exists a subsequence of length `K`  such that the sum of all elements in the subsequence equals the given `sum`.

Code:

```
for i in(1,N):
    for len  in (i-1,0):
        for sum in (0,Sum of all element)
            Possible[len+1][sum] |= Possible[len][sum-A[i]]
```

Time complexity **O(N^2.Sum)**. Is there any way to improve the time complexity to **O(N.Sum)**

Comment: This should be in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Are the numbers positive?

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge it's not a code review  i have already present a working code of `O(N*N*Sum)` now i want to improve it's time complexity which is an algorithmic problem

Comment: @GuillaumeG yes all the numbers are +ve

Comment: That's what codereview is for.

Comment: Are you also not given `K`?

Comment: This is simply the subset sum problem you can solve with dynamic programming (if all values are positive, 0 is allowed).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please explain how ? since i want to know the length of subset as well..

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what `O(N.Sum)` means? Is this linear time?

Comment: `Sum`  of all A[i] , yes it's linear time

Comment: Also, can you use a queue of length K?

Comment: What does `a [possible] subsequence sum is possible` mean?

Answer (score 1):

My function shifts a window of `k` adjacent array items across the array `A` and keeps the sum up-to-data until it matches of the search fails.

```
int getSubSequenceStart(int A[], size_t len, int sum, size_t k)
{    
    int sumK = 0;

    assert(len > 0);
    assert(k <= len);

    //  compute sum for first k items
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        sumK += A[i];
    }

    //  shift k-window upto end of A
    for (int j = k; j < len; j++)
    {
        if (sumK == sum)
        {
            return j - k;
        }

        sumK += A[j] - A[j - k];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

> Complexity is **linear** with the length of array `A`.

---

**Update for the non-contiguous general subarray case:**
To find a possibly non-contiguous subarray, you could transform your problem into a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) by subtracting `sum/k` from every element of `A` and looking for a subset with sum zero. The complexity of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is known to be exponential. Therefore, you cannot hope for a linear algorithm, unless your array A has special properties.

Comment: This reaches the goal without any overhead. Amazing!

Comment: This checks for the existence of a length-k *sublist*, not a subsequence.

Comment: Sub sequence and Sub array are different

Answer (score 0):

Let `is_subset_sum(int set[], int n, int sum)` be the function to find whether there is a subset of `set[]` with sum equal to sum. `n` is the number of elements in `set[]`.

The `is_subset_sum problem` can be divided into two subproblems

- Include the last element, recur for n = n-1, sum = sum – set[n-1]
- Exclude the last element, recur for n = n-1.

If any of the above subproblems return true, then return true.

**Following is the recursive formula for is_subset_sum() problem.**

```
is_subset_sum(set, n, sum) = is_subset_sum(set, n-1, sum) || is_subset_sum(set, n-1, sum-set[n-1])

Base Cases:

is_subset_sum(set, n, sum) = false, if sum > 0 and n == 0

is_subset_sum(set, n, sum) = true, if sum == 0
```

We can solve the problem in [Pseudo-polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) using Dynamic programming. We create a boolean 2D table subset[][] and fill it in a bottom-up manner. The value of subset[i][j] will be true if there is a subset of set[0..j-1] with sum equal to i., otherwise false. Finally, we return subset[sum][n]

The time complexity of the solution is O(sum*n).

**Implementation in C**

```
// A Dynamic Programming solution for subset sum problem

#include <stdio.h>

// Returns true if there is a subset of set[] with sun equal to given sum

bool is_subset_sum(int set[], int n, int sum) {

    // The value of subset[i][j] will be true if there is a

    // subset of set[0..j-1] with sum equal to i

    bool subset[sum+1][n+1];

    // If sum is 0, then answer is true

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)

      subset[0][i] = true;

    // If sum is not 0 and set is empty, then answer is false

    for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++)

      subset[i][0] = false;

     // Fill the subset table in botton up manner

     for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {

       for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {

         subset[i][j] = subset[i][j-1];

         if (i >= set[j-1])

           subset[i][j] = subset[i][j] || subset[i - set[j-1]][j-1];
       }

     }

    /* // uncomment this code to print table

     for (int i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {

       for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)

          printf ("%4d", subset[i][j]);

       printf("\n");

     } */

     return subset[sum][n];
}

// Driver program to test above function

int main() {

  int set[] = {3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2};

  int sum = 9;

  int n = sizeof(set)/sizeof(set[0]);

  if (is_subset_sum(set, n, sum) == true)

     printf("Found a subset with given sum");

  else

     printf("No subset with given sum");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

This could actually be solved without the queue in linear time (negative numbers allowed).

C# code:

```
bool SubsequenceExists(int[] a, int k, int sum)
{
    int currentSum = 0;
    if (a.Length < k) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < k)
        {
            currentSum += a[i];
            continue;
        }

        if (currentSum == sum) return true;
        currentSum += a[i] - a[i-k];
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Original answer:**

Assuming you can use a queue of length K something like that should do the job in linear time.

C# code:

```
bool SubsequenceExists(int[] a, int k, int sum)
{
    int currentSum = 0;
    var queue = new Queue<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < k)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(a[i]);
            currentSum += a[i];
            continue;
        }

        if (currentSum == sum) return true;
        currentSum -= queue.Dequeue();
        queue.Enqueue(a[i]);
        currentSum += a[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

The logic behind that is pretty much straightforward:

1. We populate a queue with first `K` elements while also storing its sum somewhere.
2. If the resulting sum is not equal to `sum` then we dequeue an element from the queue and add the next one from `A` (while updating the sum).
3. We repeat step 2 until we either reach the end of sequence or find the matching subsequence.

Ta-daa!